# Best practice to handle async rest service

Tags: rest, asynchronous

i'm working on a service, which should handle asyncronous requests.
It should work like this:
My service will be in the middle between consumer and backend system. The consumers could be one or many. 
The consumers send an order to my service which will be handed over to the backend system and the consumer of my service gets a "HTTP 202 Accepted".
Then the backend system need some half a day to process that order.
After processing it, the backend system will call a callback service of my impl. and i have to inform the consumer about the update of his request.

CONSUMER -SYNC-> MY SERVICES -SYNC-> BACKEND SYSTEM

CONSUMER <-ASYNC- MY SERVICES <-ASYNC- BACKEND SYSTEM

Because there could be multiple consumers, how to handle dispatching of the responses to consumers and how to handle credentials of the response service of the consumers ?

EDIT:
Its a rest service
May it be the best way to have some kind of a lookup table where i can identify which order (orderID) has been send by which consumer, so that i can forward the status update of that request back to the right consumer? 
regarding the credentials and urls of the callback services of the consumers, i just define them once in a config file and read it at runtime?
The system needs to be secured very well so sending a callback url and a api key while sending an order to my service from the consumer is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

> Because there could be multiple consumers, how to handle dispatching of the responses to consumers and how to handle credentials of the response service of the consumers ?

It might be that you are looking for [websub](https://www.w3.org/TR/websub), which includes a mechanism for [authenticated content distribution](https://www.w3.org/TR/websub/#signing-content).  Likely, you would also use [TLS Client Authentication](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-tls-client-auth/), with the hub in the role of the client.

As far as I know, you aren't required to separate the publisher from the hub; the same service can play both roles.

Comment: Hi Voice, I'm using a plattform of our company so there is no possibility to change that or implement my own base. I'm using spring boot for my service. My question is more about how to handle an async webservice the best way and if there is some kind of a framework or tool to handle the dispatching or use some kind of a caching in http to have a lookup table for dispatching.